# Nougat Crash: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libmedia.so"

Tags: android, android-ndk, dlopen, call-recording

I am working on `call recording` app where i am unable to record incoming voice in some device like Samsung S7, Gionee A1  and some other Nougat Devices. So I decided to use NDK for the purpose and added `libmedia.so` and `libutils.so` files in libs folder as these .so files are needed but getting this error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libmedia.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

Please help me to resolve this thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you already know this, but just in case:

libmedia is not an NDK API, and access to Android implementation details was restricted in Android N: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#ndk

You need to use public APIs in apps (those that are accessible in the NDK without having to `extern` them or pull libraries off the device).

> and added libmedia.so and libutils.so files in libs folder

What libs folder? If it was the lib folder in the APK then those libraries should be the ones loaded by your app rather than the ones in /system/lib64. Are you sure you got them in the right path in the APK?